Centers and conjugacy classes of groups relative to a pair of group homomorphisms
$\newcommand{\defeq}{\mathbin{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}}$Given a group $G$, its center $\mathrm{Z}(G)$ and set of conjugacy classes $\mathrm{Cl}(G)$ are defined by
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Z}(G)  &\defeq \{b\in G\ |\ \text{$ab=ba$ for each $a\in G$}\},\\
\mathrm{Cl}(G) &\defeq G/(a\sim b^{-1}ab).
\end{align*}
The following generalisation of these notions has recently shown up naturally in my research: let $f,g\colon G\rightrightarrows H$ be group homomorphisms. Define the centre and set of conjugacy classes of $H$ relative to $(f,g)$ by
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Z}_H(f,g)  &\defeq \{b\in H\ |\ \text{$bf(a)=g(a)b$ for each $a\in G$}\},\\
\mathrm{Cl}_H(f,g) &\defeq H/(b\sim f(a)^{-1}bg(a)).
\end{align*}
Note that taking $G=H$ and $f=g=\mathrm{id}_{G}$ recovers the usual notions of the centre and set of conjugacy classes of $G$.
Question. Have these notions been studied before? Do they lead to interesting applications in the same way that centres and conjugacy classes do?

Edit: As LSpice mentioned in the comments, there are a couple notions that have been studied that fit as special cases of the notions in the question body:

When $f$ and $g$ are inclusions of subgroups (or group subschemes) $H$ and $K$ into a group (or group scheme) $G$, what I called $\mathrm{Z}_{H}(f,g)$ above is often called the transporter $\mathrm{Trans}_{G}(H,K)$ of $H$ into $K$; see e.g. this question on MSE.
There's a notion of twisted conjugacy starting with a group $G$, an automorphism $\phi\colon G\to G$ of $G$, and defined by $a\sim g^{-1}a\phi(g)^{-1}$, corresponding to $\mathrm{Cl}_{G}(\mathrm{id}_{G},\phi)$. See e.g. here or here.

I'm also interested in the following extra questions:
Extra Question I. Are the globalizations of $\mathrm{Z}_{H}(f,g)$ and $\mathrm{Cl}_{H}(f,g)$ useful notions in the setting of group schemes? Do they lead to any interesting applications?
Extra Question II. Are $\mathrm{Z}_{H}(f,g)$ and $\mathrm{Cl}_{H}(f,g)$ useful in representation theory, be it of finite groups or topological ones?
Extra Question III. Have $\mathrm{Z}_{H}(f,g)$ and $\mathrm{Cl}_{H}(f,g)$ been studied¹ in the setting of semigroups and monoids?
¹Here we replace $\sim$ by the relation generated by $f(a)b\sim bg(a)$.

If you H as a G-biset via the two maps then this starts to look like biset home G to H and the tensor product over GxG^op of G with H.

$Z_H(f, g)$ is often called the transporter of $f$ to $g$ (in the $H$-set of homomorphisms $G \to H$). It's a bit unexpected to call this a generalised centre, since it might be empty, and never contains the identity for $f \ne g$.

@LSpice Thanks! Is there some place where I can read more about this? I've tried searching a bit for the name "transporters", but didn't find any interesting resources on them.

Re, I'm mostly familiar with them in the context of algebraic groups, where one might slightly generalise the statement that the normaliser of a subgroup is algebraic to the statement that the transporter of one subscheme to another is algebraic; I don't know any applications that aren't just easy generalisations of statements about normalisers.

In that same vein, with $G = \mathbf G(\overline{\mathbb F_q})$, $H = G$, $f = 1$ and $g = \operatorname{Frob}$, one often calls your equivalence relation "twisted conjugacy."  In this context, the twisted conjugacy classes are in bijection with the orbits of $G$ on ${(g, \operatorname{Frob}) : g \in G} \subseteq G \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

@LSpice Thank you so much for the explanation! Have you ever seen any applications (or discussions) of transporters where $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be general maps of group schemes, rather than subscheme inclusions?

Re, I have not, although I do immediately think of Fong and Griess - An infinite family of elementwise conjugate non-conjugate homomorphisms.

Twisted conjugacy generalises to "double-twisted conjugacy", which relates to the Generalised (or Non-Homogeneous) Post Correspondence Problem. This was originally posed for free monoids, which is why I mention it, but has been studied for groups (https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5246, https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12158). For groups, this takes two group homomorphisms $f, g:H\to K$ and a pair of elements $u, v\in K$, and asks if there exists a non-trivial word $x\in H$ such that $uf(x)v=g(x)$. The case of $u=v^{-1}$ corresponds to the situation here, and is undecidable for free groups.
